# Pygame: Can't seek in this data source

Tags: python, pygame

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "G:/Computing/Project/Main.py", line 32, in <module>
    ClubsImages, SpadesImages, HeartsImages, DiamondsImages = LoadImages()
  File "G:/Computing/Project/Main.py", line 18, in LoadImages
    ClubsImages[i] = pygame.image.load(("Images/",x,".png"))
pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source
```

I get this error when I run this code:

```
def LoadImages():
    SpadesImages = {}
    ClubsImages = {}
    HeartsImages = {}
    DiamondsImages = {}
    x = 1
    for i in range (13):
        ClubsImages[i] = pygame.image.load(("Images/",x,".png"))
        x+=1
        SpadesImages[i] = pygame.image.load(("Images/",x,".png"))
        x+=1
        HeartsImages[i] = pygame.image.load(("Images/",x,".png"))
        x+=1
        DiamondsImages[i] = pygame.image.load(("Images/",x,".png"))
        x+=1
    return ClubsImages, SpadesImages, HeartsImages, DiamondsImages
```

I have read files like this before, except this is the first time I have tried to do it into an array and in a loop. The problem is not the loop so I have taken that out and tried it and I get an identical error. So I am thinking it's the array. I can't see any reason that you couldn't read images into an array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're passing a tuple to `pygame.image.load`.  According to the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) for the function, it can either take a filename (as a string), or a file object and an optional name hint.  Looking closely at your call:

```
pygame.image.load(("Images/", x, ".png"))
```

You are passing `("Images/", x, ".png")`, a tuple, which could not be interpreted as a filepath.  Try something like:

```
pygame.image.load("Images/" + str(x) + ".png")
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has solved my issue (well i think so, it doesnt give me an error but i havent actually tried to use any of the images yet)

Comment: @GavinHenderson5 Happy to help.  Since this fixed this particular issue, don't forget to accept the answer and post another question if you run into another problem.