# Pygame "Can't seek in this data source"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The project structure is as follows:

```
app
    start.py
    src
        main.py
        __init__.py
    Pictures
        testing_001.png
```

start.py:

```
import src.main
src.main.main()
```

src.main:

```
def main():
    full_path = os.path.join(("Pictures","test_001.png"))
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(full_path)
    except pygame.error as message:
        debug("Cannot load image:%s" % str(full_path))
        raise SystemExit(message)
```

I get error "Can't seek in this data source", what have I done wrong?, what have I done wrong?

Note that I am using **Python 3** and **Pygame** is built against it.
I have checked [pygame-cant-seek-in-this-data-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024728/pygame-cant-seek-in-this-data-source), however, I do not think I am passing a tuple to `pygame.image.load()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I do not think I am passing a tuple to `pygame.image.load()`"

Check again :-).  The arguments to `os.path.join` are supposed to be strings, but you're passing a `tuple`.  The behavior here isn't specified by the documentation (my guess is that this would fit in the "undefined behavior" category), but it appears that `os.path` is simply returning the input in this case.

```
>>> os.path.join(("Pictures", "test_001.png"))
('Pictures', 'test_001.png')
```

You probably wanted:

```
>>> os.path.join("Pictures", "test_001.png")
'Pictures/test_001.png'
```